# Create a grid with specific indices

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, vertices

I need a Mesh (640x480) with vertex-indices for 0 to 639 in the first row, 640 to 1279 in the second row, and so on.... I will try to show what I mean in the picture:

[image]

First, I tried to use a Plane and subdivide it, but by doing that it destroy any useful indices of the Vertices. In my second attempt I use:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_grid_add(radius=1, view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, -0, layers=(True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False))
```

to create a Grid with bpy. It creates a 10x10 Mesh (9 faces a row), with indices like I need. Now it just have to be bigger. Does someone know a command to create a Grid like I need with the 640x480 vertices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add the x and y subdivisions argument:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_grid_add(x_subdivisions=640, y_subdivisions=480, radius=1, view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0), layers=(True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False))
```

Comment: Wow - you are rescuing me - i seems to work perfectly.